# Terminology: meaning of the term 'saga'

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I just went through the documentation for using Redux-sagas to manage asynchronous actions with generator functions.
The documentation is clear and looks promising but at the end I'm a bit confused about what the accurate description of the term 'saga' is supposed to be in front end development.

This background-document linked by the Redux-Saga docs: 
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/cs711/2002fa/reading/sagas.pdf
mentions:

> A LLT (Long Lived Transaction) is a saga if it can be written as a
>   sequence of transactions that can be interleaved with other
>   transactions.

Basically, what they refer to is the optimisation of long lived database transactions by *relaxing the requirement that an LLT is to be executed as an atomic action*.

Could you clarify how 'saga' translates to overall front-end development?
I'm sure it has something to do with async request management, but I'm rather blurry on the exact description of the term (when relatef to front end). Managing async flows doesn't really seem new to me, but the term 'saga' rather is.

Edit: 
In the scope of speaking a common language, it seemed important to me. If the question is not relevant, please add in comment why and I'll remove the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In redux-saga your sagas are written as generator functions that yield a sequence of side effects. You can think of each of these side effects as the "sub-transactions." Obviously one is written about databases and the other a JS state management framework (which in a sense is a "database" for a front end app), so a similar approach can be applied to running complex, potentially async sequences of logic on those data. I believe that's inspiration behind the implementation of redux-saga and the reason for calling them sagas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then it's as I suspected; that the term 'saga' is rather used here in isolation to this library specifically (being inspired as you mention it). In the future, I feel that generator functions will increasingly be used for managing async flows, but not sure if the term 'saga' will become an official term in front end-development and I don't feel too comfortable with using the term too often just yet. Multiple blog posts seem to keep a slightly different (yet important) semantic meaning of what a saga is supposed to be, some using the term more loosely than others.